# How do I conditionally choose between two fields of a struct and then update the chosen one?

Tags: rust, ownership

I have two structs of the same type inside a larger struct. I will select one of the structs and perform updates using the same code.

A simplified version:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Counts {
    value: u16,
    count: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Partitioned {
    even: Counts,
    odd: Counts,
}

fn sort() -> Partitioned {
    let mut even = Counts { value: 2, count: 0 };

    let mut odd = Counts { value: 3, count: 0 };

    for i in 1..30 {
        let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { even } else { odd };
        s.count = s.count + 1;
        // ... a lot of other code
    }

    Partitioned { even, odd }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", sort());
}
```

This does not compile with complaints about ownership:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `even`
  --> src/main.rs:19:37
   |
19 |         let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { even } else { odd };
   |                                     ^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `even` has type `Counts`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `odd`
  --> src/main.rs:19:51
   |
19 |         let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { even } else { odd };
   |                                                   ^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `odd` has type `Counts`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `even`
  --> src/main.rs:24:19
   |
19 |         let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { even } else { odd };
   |                                     ---- value moved here
...
24 |     Partitioned { even, odd }
   |                   ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `even` has type `Counts`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `odd`
  --> src/main.rs:24:25
   |
19 |         let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { even } else { odd };
   |                                                   --- value moved here
...
24 |     Partitioned { even, odd }
   |                         ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `odd` has type `Counts`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

What is going on here? How can I implement it without copying all the update code to both blocks of the `if`?

Answer (score 1):

Take [a mutable reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references) to the field:

```
let mut s = if i % 2 == 0 { &mut even } else { &mut odd };
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I will get these ownership rules down eventually. :)

Comment: @RobertSimmonsJr. please be sure to let me know how I can improve the answer.